# What is {shadow-ig-media-id}?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api

I've received a notification that my app has reached 100% of the hourly rate limit and all API calls to my app will fail until it falls below the throttling limit.
This was also part of the notification:
Here's a breakdown of the methods causing your app to hit the rate limit:
By Call Count:
GET {shadow-ig-media-id}/comments 102%

What is this {shadow-ig-media-id} means? I couldn't find anything about it. Also, my average API activity shows 0 calls for the last 7 days, which couldn't be correct if I hit the rate limit.

I'm using the latest API endpoint with the official Facebook PHP SDK.

Comment: The “shadow ig” part probably refers to “Page-backed Instagram accounts”, these are referred to as “shadow accounts” as well, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/instagramads/v2.9#pbia So `{shadow-ig-media-id}` would then simply mean this is the id of a media object belonging to such a shadow account.

Comment: Thank you @04FS This makes sense. 
Based on the documentation you linked these kinds of profiles can create only ads on Instagram. Does this mean that someone was trying to list the comments of an ad and that is what hit the rate limit?

Comment: Comments on the ad, or the media item itself (if that is its own, separate entity - not sure if those are identical in this scenario.)

Comment: Thank you for your help @04FS I'm not sure where the problem is but I can continue investigating based on these.